# HttpServer tcpConfiguration Deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I moved to Spring 2.3.1.RELEASE to 2.4.5.

HttpServer tcpConfiguration Deprecated with new version. How can i configure NioEventLoopGroup with Spring boot 2.4.5.

```
    public NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory(NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup) {
        NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
        factory.setServerCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(new NettyServerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
                return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(tcpServer ->
                        tcpServer.bootstrap(serverBootstrap -> serverBootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
                                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)));
            }
        }));
        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use directly the [HttpServer#runOn](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/transport/Transport.html#runOn-io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup-) API. The snippet above should be looking like this:

```
public NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory(NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup) {
    NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
    factory.setServerCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(new NettyServerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
            return httpServer.runOn(eventLoopGroup);
        }
    }));
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to access the server bootstrap ?

Comment: In the recent versions Reactor Netty DOES NOT use `ServerBootstrap` anymore. Everything that you can add as a configuration via `ServerBootstrap`, you can add using Reactor Netty API.